# Link to a nested emberData object in emberJS

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using emberData and I have the following model

```
App.Product = DS.Model.extend({
  page_title: DS.attr('string'),
  image: DS.attr('string'),
  shop: DS.belongsTo('App.Shop', {embedded: true}),
  style: (function() {
    return "background-image:url('" + this.get("image") + "')";
  })
});
```

The JSON data looks like this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  image: 'imageUrl',
  shop: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'shopName'
  }
}
```

In my template I want to link to the a page to display the shop

```
<img {{bindAttr src="image"}}>
{{#linkTo "shop" shop}}Store{{/linkTo}}
```

Unfortunately it links to `http://localhost:3000/#/shop/undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to embed the model that it `belongsTo`. The breaking changes document  states that you embed objects in a parent object:

From [BREAKING_CHANGES.md](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/BREAKING_CHANGES.md)

> Embedded in Parent
>
> An adapter can save one-to-many relationships by embedding IDs (or
>   records) in the parent object. In this case, the relationship is not
>   considered acknowledged until both the old parent and new parent have
>   acknowledged the change.
>
> In this case, the adapter should keep track of the old parent and new
>   parent, and acknowledge the relationship change once both have
>   acknowledged. If one of the two sides does not exist (e.g. the new
>   parent does not exist because of nulling out the belongs-to
>   relationship), the adapter should acknowledge the relationship once
>   the other side has acknowledged.

Your fixture must be:

```
App.Product.FIXTURES = [{
  id: 1,
  image: "imageUrl",
  shop_id: 2
}];
```

Comment: Mhmm, this changes nothing, still got `#/shop/undefined`

Comment: Ok, it must `shop_id` instead of just `shop` as key for the id. Could you please update your answer, so I can accept it.